Google Legacy Cloud Notifications to Firebase Notifications
I'm in the process of converting some code that sends Google Cloud Notifications to an Android app so that it uses the more modern Firebase notifications.
My appliction is in Java and uses direct HTTPS connections to post the messages. I've done this before with another project, so I'm familiar with the steps.
I'm at the point where I can post the message and receive back a 200 response, including the ID of the sent message in the body. So it would appear that I am doing everything correctly.
However, my app never receives the notification. I know the app works because I can still post the Google Cloud notification and the app does receive it.
I'm wondering what could possibly cause this situation, in other words, under what circumstances could Firebase report success but no message is received by the app?
Thanks,
Frank

On further analysis it appears that my app is in fact receiving the message, but isn't reacting to it the way it used to. In particular, it used to pop up an alert and put something in the notificaction bar.
